# Value passed from textbox to textarea is automatically deleted

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to pass a value entered in a textbox to a text area. However when I run my code the value appears in the textarea and it disapears.

Html code:

```
        Customer Name
        <input type="text" id="name1TXT" />                        

       <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="productList">

       </textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
function transferData() {
        var customer = document.getElementById("name1TXT").value;

        if (customer != "")
            document.getElementById('productList').value += customer + ","

        document.getElementById('name1TXT').value = "";
    }
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

**Edit**
Here is all of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title></title>

<style>

    .calcFrm {

    }

</style>
```

```
<table style="width:300px;" border="1">

    <tr>

        <td>Customer Name</td>

        <td><input type="text" id="name1TXT" /></td> 

    </tr>

    <tr>

       <td>Coating</td>

       <td>
            <select class="coating1DDL">
            <option value="1">Galvanized</option>
            <option value="2">Powder Coat</option>
            <option value="3">None</option>
            </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Weight</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="weight1TXT" onkeyup="sum1();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Length</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="length1TXT" onkeyup="sum1();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pieces</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pcs1TXT" onkeyup="sum1();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Pounds</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pounds1TXT" onkeyup="sum1();"readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Tons</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="tons1TXT" onkeyup="convertPounds1();" readonly="readonly" /></td>           
    </tr>       
</table>
<table style="width:300px;" border="1" class="tonsFrm2">
    <tr>
        <td>Customer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name2TXT" /></td>          
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Coating</td>
       <td>
            <select class="coating2DDL">
            <option>Galvanized</option>
            <option>Powder Coat</option>
            <option>None</option>
            </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Weight</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="weight2TXT" onkeyup="sum2();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Length</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="length2TXT" onkeyup="sum2()"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pieces</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pcs2TXT" onkeyup="sum2();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Pounds</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pounds2TXT" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="sum2();" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Tons</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="tons2TXT" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="convertPounds2();" /></td>           
    </tr>       
</table>
<table style="width:300px;" border="1" class="tonsFrm3">
    <tr>            
        <td>Customer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="text3TXT" /></td>             
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Coating</td>
       <td>
            <select class="coating3DDL">
            <option>Galvanized</option>
            <option>Powder Coat</option>
            <option>None</option>
            </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Weight</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="weight3TXT" onkeyup="sum3();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Length</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="length3TXT" onkeyup="sum3();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pieces</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pcs3TXT" onkeyup="sum3();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Pounds</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="pounds3TXT" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="sum3();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Tons</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="tons3TXT" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="convertPounds3();" /></td>           
    </tr>       
</table>
<button onclick="transferData()">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
<button type="button">Add New Form</button>
<br />
Pounds Total
<input type="text" id="TotalPoundsTxt" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="totalPounds();" />
Tons Total
<input type="text" id="TotalTonsTXT" readonly="readonly" onkeyup="totalTons();" />
<br />
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="productList">

</textarea>
<br />
<button type="button">Save Input</button>
```

Javascript:

```
    //number correlate with form in order

    //functions for first form

    function sum1() {

        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('weight1TXT').value;

        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('length1TXT').value;

        var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pcs1TXT').value;

        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) * parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue);

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('pounds1TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function convertPounds1() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('pounds1TXT').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) / 2000;
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('tons1TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function galvCalc1() {
        var galvOption = document.getElementById('').value
    }
    //functions for second form 
    function sum2() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('weight2TXT').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('length2TXT').value;
        var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pcs2TXT').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) * parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('pounds2TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function convertPounds2() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('pounds2TXT').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) / 2000;
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('tons2TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    //Functions for third form
    function sum3() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('weight3TXT').value;
        var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('length3TXT').value;
        var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('pcs3TXT').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) * parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('pounds3TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function convertPounds3() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('pounds3TXT').value;
        var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) / 2000;
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('tons3TXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function totalPounds(){
        var firstpoundvalue = document.getElementById('pounds1TXT').value;

        var secondpoundvalue = document.getElementById('pounds2TXT').value;

        var thirdpoundvalue = document.getElementById('pounds3TXT').value;

        var result = parseInt(firstpoundvalue) + parseInt(secondpoundvalue) + parseInt(thirdpoundvalue);

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('TotalPoundsTxt').value = result;
        }

    }

    function totalTons() {
        var firsttonvalue = document.getElementById('tons1TXT').value;

        var secondtonvalue = document.getElementById('tons2TXT').value;

        var thirdtonvalue = document.getElementById('tons3TXT').value;

        var result = parseInt(firsttonvalue) + parseInt(secondtonvalue) + parseInt(thirdtonvalue);

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('TotalTonsTXT').value = result;
        }

    }
    function transferData() {
        var customer = document.getElementById("name1TXT").value;

        if (customer != "")
            document.getElementById('productList').value += customer + ",";


    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you calling transferdata function please provide full code or jsfiddle..

Comment: Remove the last line of your function

Comment: I just copied exactly what you had there, and added a onChange event to run the functon.  It works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment but I created as [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/guperipo/3/edit?html,js,output) and seems to be working. I wasn't for sure how you are calling the `transferData` function to see the textarea clear so I just added an `onBlur` event to the input textbox.

I also added a semicolon to the line clearing the `name1TXT` value.

I still think everything is working regarding your code. By that I mean there aren't any odd bugs. But what exactly are you trying to accomplish? There appears to be 3 Customer Name boxes but when you click submit only 1 is being output into the textarea. It only grabs Customer1 and puts his/her name into the textarea and this process is repeating with each Submit. Are you trying to add all 3 customers? If so, then you will need more logic in your `transferData` function

Comment: Right I'm working my way up to that point. I'm trying to get the first textbox to work and then work on adding in the other two. However for this to work I need the customer name to be added to the textarea and stay there.

Comment: Check out the JSBin link I have. It is staying there. You can keep adding to the name1TXT and clicking submit (or blur in this case) and it keeps appending the names in the textarea.

Comment: [Here is a better JSBin which includes all your code](http://jsbin.com/jodug/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Sorry about that your right it does work. So could I just change onblur to onclick?

Comment: Never mind it work exactly how I wanted it to! Thank you! What was I missing?

Comment: So I tried my code in both IE and FireFox and it doesn't work like it is in your JSBin. Do you know why it might do that?

Comment: The JSBin is just a copy of your code. Check all spelling. Check that semicolons are inserted where appropriate. I know you were missing a couple. The JSBin runs find for me in FF31.

Answer (score 0):

you should use value like this

```
document.getElementById("writeArea").value = txt;
```

or like this in jQuery:

```
$('#myTextarea').val('');
```